# Determine the matrix of the differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Determine the matrix of the differentiation operator $\dfrac{d}{dx}: P_n\longrightarrow P_{n-1}$ with respect to the natural bases.

Any polynomial in $P_n$ is $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$. So if I differentiate we get $na_nx^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+\dots+a_1$

but don't know what to do.

Comment: Think about the various terms $x^n$ as the bases.  Then, we can associate vectors with polynomials.  Consider the linear case: $a+bx \rightarrow (a,b)$.  The derivative is represented as $(b,0)$, so the derivative matrix would be $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$$.  Now you can generalize to the $n^{th}$ order case.

Comment: @jcandy this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I didn't want to give an answer but just a hint.

Comment: @jcandy the matrix corresponding to D is I got, $a_{ij}=j$ if $i=j-1$ and $0$ otherwise. Is my answer ok? Here, $i=0(1)n$, $j=0(1)n$

Comment: Yeah, if you want to start indexing at 0, that's alright.  It might be a bit clearer to write the nonzero elements as simply $a_{i-1,i} = i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: @jcandy thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $D$ be the differentiation operator. Let $\{1, x, \dots, x^j \}$ be the canonical basis for $P_j$. For every $f \in P_n$,
\begin{align*}
Df = D (\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j ) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j D x^j = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_{i,j} x^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left( \sum_{j=0}^n a_j c_{i,j}\right) x^i.
\end{align*}
This means if we know the action of the operator on every basis vector, we know the full information of the operator.

Now we identify the vectors in $P_n$ and $P_{n-1}$ by column vectors and let $A$ be the matrix representation of $T$.
\begin{align*}
A = [Av_1, Av_2, \dots, Av_n],
\end{align*}
where $v_j$'s are canonical basis vectors identified as column vectors .

Equivalently, if we define the coordinate operator $C_{P_{n-1}}$ that isomorphically identify the elements in $P_{n-1}$ by column vectors,
\begin{align*}
A = [C_{P_{n-1}} T x^0, C_{P_{n-1}} T x^1, \dots,  C_{P_{n-1}} T x^n].
\end{align*}

Comment: I could not understand the answer. Anyway, the matrix corresponding to D is I got, $a_{ij}=j$ if $i=j-1$ and $0$ otherwise. Is my answer ok? Here, $i=0(1)\overline{n-1}$, $j=0(1)n$

Comment: sorry, minor error in the last comment: $i=0(1)n$